# CodeIgniter Display MySQL Count

Tags: php, codeigniter

View

```
<h3><?php echo $wonCount; ?></h3>
```

Controller

```
$this->load->model('coupon_model');
$data['wonCount'] = $this->coupon_model->wonCount();
$this->loadPage('dashboard', $data);
```

Model

```
public function wonCount() {

    return $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(status) FROM coupon WHERE status = 'won'");
}
```

Error :

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: wonCount

How can I display count?

Comment: Before sending the data to the view check whether the wonCount value is set or not and change the load view line to $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);

Answer (score 1):

you need to send a query result (you can use row() in case you only expect one row to be returned, like in your example) back to the controller and use an alias in your query:

so write in your model something like:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(status) as my_count FROM coupon WHERE status = 'won'");
return ($query->num_rows() ) ?$query->row()->my_count:false;
```

now, with your code example in controller and view, the variable `$wonCount` will echo out in your view correctly

more on Generating Query Result Rows [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows)

Comment: It is still same didn't change anything

Comment: if no result, it's because COUNT(status) is 0

Comment: Another error occurred for return line. Message: Trying to get property of non-object. By the way I don't have to use array If it is easire I can use object.

Comment: I'm off for dinner, please check if there is no spelling error in your code. Also if following the link of CI docs you should be able to track down the error, use and abuse print_r($data) to control if the return is as desired.